# Hover colour spreading out beyond submit button

Tags: css

I have been struggling with this for two days now, I am using  a plugin called wpform to create an order form. Everything is fine except the submit button, as soon as you hover on the submit button you will see the ugly orange colour spreading beyond the submit button. How do I resolve this, any help here is the link to the problem  http://dansarki.sqtdemo.com.ng/order-form/

Answer (score 2):

That's happening because of css rule. Here's how you can solve this:

1. Navigate to: `wp-content/themes/wp-store/style.css`
2. Go to line `452`, you'll see below code

   ```
   button:hover:after {
     opacity: 1;
     filter: alpha(opacity= 100);
     visibility: visible;
     width: 100%;
   }
   ```
3. Set the opacity to `0` OR remove this style completely.

**NOTE:**

1. I recommend you to create child theme, and make modifications there.
2. Please be aware, it will remove this styling from all other buttons.

Comment: you are a genius man, I owe you a beer. You just saved me from a heart attack.

Comment: I need a favour please man, how did yuu trace the problem to that stylesheet thanks.